# Query c# code DOM

Tags: .net

I would like to issue queries against a C#/.Net code base in order to get instances that match that query.

For instance could I currently get all method A's which do not have a return value and which call ClassB.MethodB? Or all methods which operate on class variables and so on.

Is this easily possible?

Comment: You can do such a search in VS object browser, It's possible to code so, but may be not so easy. e.g you can get all dll names, iterate on them and their methods and attributes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx